# What is the simplest way to create custom decorative LED-lighting?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I have always wanted to build decorative lamps with LEDs (application example: imagine a model boat with Xmas lights).

Is there a way (commercial, or custom-built) to power several LEDs, so that:

- The power supply is compact, elegant, and wall-pluggable (not battery-powered)
- There are simple and robust ways to wire the individual LEDs
- The whole thing doesn't cost much ? (in the order of tens of USD for the power supply + LEDs + connectivity)

I know that I can buy plain LEDs from electronic manufacturers, build a power supply with my bare hands, recycle an AC/DC adapter from a phone charger, solder everything and have it running cheaply. I know (more or less) how to do this, but it would take me a long time and the result would be ugly and dirty.
On the other hand, I know that there are now LED systems that can be screwed just like a light bulb, but this is not what I am after either.

Are there any intermediate solutions that would be adequate for the above needs ?

Comment: what about solar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you define elegant so I'll leave that parameter out.

You can buy LED power supply on ebay, the LED-strip or other LED-array on ebay and connect them. There is somewhat of a standard that doesn't require soldering for LED-strips.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea, I didn't know that they were so simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using the same approach that commercial manufacturers use for LED holiday lights.

I did a project that did this recently; you can find directions [here](http://www.riderx.info/post/Make-your-own-LED-Ornamentse280a6.aspx). Note that this approach connects directly to line current and there is the potential for injury.

Comment: Answers on SE are required to contain the relevant content referenced in any external links. Please 1) updated the link, and 2) include some or all of the content here.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this website when I was looking for some made to measure LED strip because I couldn't be bothered with all the hassle of soldering. All I did was email them with my spec and they got back to me with a great solution. Hope this helps you http://www.downlightsdirect.co.uk/led-strip.html

Comment: Answers that rely on a URL don't work well on SE (links tend to go stale). See the [faq] for more details.